# Ruby on Rails -- Faye Framework -- private_pub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chat, publish-subscribe, faye

I'm using private_pub to implement a one-to-one chat-like application.

Here is my story: as a user, I would like to receive a message when my partner leaves the chat – closes the window, etc.

Looking through the [Faye Monitoring docs](http://faye.jcoglan.com/node/monitoring.html) here is my attempt at binding on `unsubscribe`:

---

```
# Run with: rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
require "bundler/setup"
require "yaml"
require "faye"
require "private_pub"
require "active_support/core_ext"

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

PrivatePub.load_config(File.expand_path("../config/private_pub.yml", __FILE__),     ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development")

wts_pubsub = PrivatePub.faye_app

wts_pubsub.bind(:subscribe) do |client_id, channel|
puts "[#{Time.now}] Client #{client_id} joined  #{channel}"
end

wts_pubsub.bind(:unsubscribe) do |client_id, channel|
  puts "[#{Time.now}] Client #{client_id} disconnected from #{channel}"
  PrivatePub.publish_to channel, { marius_says: 'quitter' }
end

run wts_pubsub
```

---

but I keep getting timeouts: `[ERROR] [Faye::RackAdapter] Timeout::Error`

Prying into `PrivatePub#publish_to`, data holds what I expect both when I'm publishing from the Rails or the private_pub app, but the private_pub app keeps hanging.

How can I get publishing from private_pub to work?

Comment: This thread is somewhat old; have you figured out what the problem is? I've been spending hours on this exact problem without much success.

Answer (score 0):

Your second bind should be to `disconnect` event instead of `unsubscribe`.

Also, remember to fire off a Faye/PrivatePub `disconnect` event in your client side code when a browser window is closed.

*Note:* You might need to do this for all open sessions with the Faye server or just on a channel by channel basis based on chat application's design

In plain JS this might be something like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = functionThatTriggersFayeDisconnectEvent;
```

Sorry for not using proper markup, posting from mobile.

Comment: Both `disconnect` and `unsubscribe` events are automatically triggered when closing the tab – here is the [modified private_pub.rb](https://gist.github.com/mariusbutuc/8cdd6d71e7595a2fb814#file-private_pub-rb) and [its output](https://gist.github.com/mariusbutuc/8cdd6d71e7595a2fb814#file-private_pub-out). Doesn't seem to solve the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research and numerous attempts, this is the solution I found:

Replace `PrivatePub.publish_to channel, { marius_says: 'quitter' }` with:

```
system "curl http://localhost:9292/faye -d 'message={\"channel\":\"#{channel}\", \"data\":{\"channel\":\"#{channel}\",\"data\":{\"message\":{\"content\":\"#{client_id} disconnected from this channel.\"}}}, \"ext\":{\"private_pub_token\":\"ADD_APPROPRIATE_SECRET_HERE\"}}' &"
```

This will trigger an asynchronous request (curl + &) which will bypass the problem. Not the best fix, but it works.